# Improvement of Alpha Expression

Tags: finance, quant-trading-strategies, optimization

I'm newbie user of Websim ([websim](https://websim.worldquantchallenge.com/en/cms/wqc/websim/)), given

Alpha Expression : (est_eps * (cashflow/sharesout) * (est_sales/sharesout))/est_dividend_ps

Settings-Region:USA, Universe:TOP3000, delay:1,MAX stock weight : 0.05, decay:5.

the problem is the error message

Alpha weight is too strongly concentrated or too a few stocks are assigned weight.

How to remedy this?

Comment: Firstly, you should edit this to form an actual question.  Secondly, I would adjust the formula a bit so that you aren't just favoring companies with large revenue projections (est_sales) large cashflows.  For example, using cashflow per share and sales per share would make more sense then notional cash flow and notional forward sales.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! the alpha was average before, its Excellent now!    
New expression : ((est_eps * (cashflow/sharesout) * (est_sales/sharesout))/est_dividend_ps)
But the problem still persist Alpha weight is too strongly concentrated or too a few stocks are assigned weight, hence can't submit the alpha.

Comment: "can't submit the alpha" --I have no idea what this means.

Comment: I'm using Websim, any other suggestion so that more stocks are assigned weight & reduce the concentration?

Comment: Most of us are newbie users of websim, could you explain the terminology?

Comment: Try to set MAX STOCK WEIGHT to a smaller value (but still bigger than 0).

Comment: @noob2 I set the MAX Stock weight to 0.01 but the performance drops from excellent to good which is fine, but the error of strong concentration still remains. Any modifications to the expressions?